# How to correct this free body diagram for two masses on eachother on a table?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, friction

Assuming this arrangement,

[image: arangement]

And that the upper mass is lighter than the lower one, And that the coefficient of friction between the two masses is $\mu$, And the table is frictionless, this is the free body diagram I have drawn.

[image: free body diagram]

But it must have an error. Because if the force applied isn't more than maximum static friction, then the net force applied to M will be zero. But we know that the system will move.

How to correct it?

Comment: The table is frictionless.  This means that there is no friction force between the table and the larger mass.

Comment: That f in the diagram is the force of friction and its reaction force. Not anything related to table.

Comment: For a frictionless table, block M will accelerate for all values of F>0.  There is an error in your analysis.

Comment: Nothing here says that the static friction between them will be maximal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll provide a complete solution to the case where the friction force is fully developed. I'm not entirely sure where your confusion arises, but I hope this will make the situation clear to you. Mechanics is difficult and there are lots of places you can make mistakes (I really hope that I haven't messed up myself).

First assume that all motion will be horizontal, so $\vec{a}_1 = a_1 \hat{i}$, $\vec{a}_2 = a_2 \hat{i}$. Then draw the free-body diagram and write down the force equations for the two blocks and the relation between friction and normal force:

[image: Free-body diagram and equations]

Now that we have five equations, we can solve for our five unknowns ($a_1$, $a_2$, $N_1$, $N_2$ and $F_f$):

$$ \left.\begin{aligned}
    N_1 - mg &= 0 \\ F_f &= ma_1 \\
    N_2 - Mg - N_1 &= 0 \\ F - F_f &= Ma_2 \\ F_f &= \mu N_1
\end{aligned}\right\} \implies
\left\{\begin{aligned}
    N_1 &= mg \\ N_2 &= (M+m)g \\ F_f &= \mu mg \\ a_1 &= \mu g \\
    a_2 &= \frac{F - \mu mg}{M}
\end{aligned}\right. $$

In the case where the friction isn't fully developed we don't have $F_f = \mu N_1$ anymore, just $F_f < \mu N_1$. So just four equations but still five unknowns. But we can get another equation if we realise that $F_f$ is just the right value to prevent any relative motion between the blocks; $v_1 = v_2$ always and so $a_1 = a_2$. Now we have five equations again, and can solve the resulting system:

$$ \left.\begin{aligned}
    N_1 - mg &= 0 \\ F_f &= ma_1 \\
    N_2 - Mg - N_1 &= 0 \\ F - F_f &= Ma_2 \\ a_1 &= a_2
\end{aligned}\right\} \implies
\left\{\begin{aligned}
    N_1 &= mg \\ N_2 &= (M+m)g \\ F_f &= \frac{mF}{M+m} \\
    a_1 &= \frac{F}{M+m} \\
    a_2 &= \frac{F}{M+m}
\end{aligned}\right. $$

As a bonus, we can actually find the value of $F$ for which the blocks start gliding relative to each other by requiring that $F_f = \mu N_1$ in this solution (or alternatively, requiring that $a_1 = a_2$ in the previous solution):

$$ F_f = \mu N_1 \implies \frac{mF}{M+m} = \mu mg \implies
F = \mu(M+m)g $$
or alternatively
$$ a_1 = a_2 \implies \mu g = \frac{F - \mu mg}{M} \implies
F = \mu(M+m)g. $$

Both ways give the same result (we've just solved the system of all six equations with $F$ as a new unknown).

Answer (score 2):

> Because if the force applied isn't more than maximum static friction, then the net force applied to M will be zero

This is incorrect. Nothing in this problem says that the static friction must be overcome.

There is only static friction between the two boxes, and *if* it reached it's maximum, then *the top box* would start sliding and not holding on. It's not about the motion of the bottom box but rather about if the two are able to hold on to each other.

So the short answer: **Nothing is wrong in the free body diagram. The mistake is to assume static friction to equal the force $F$.**

Comment: That assumption arised from the fact that if you try to pull a block on a non-ideal surface without having its value greater than $\mu N$, then it will not move (your force will be canceled by that of static). I thought that there aren't more than two forces on the bottom M. So these two forces are the ones who get canceled by eachother.

Comment: @AHB If there was friction with the floor, then yes. Static friction will grow as much as needed to hold on to the bottom box, so it doesn't move. $F$ has to overcome the maximum limit of that friction, to rip it loose. At the same time, the friction *between* the boxes also grows to be large enough to hold on to them both and prevent them from sliding. But it achieves that - they *don't* start sliding. No need for it to grow all the way to its maximum value, and no reason to assume that it must equal or be close to $F$. It just has to be enough, whatever value that might be.

Answer (score 1):

1) Draw a free body force diagram for each mass.

2) Think about the frictional force between the two masses. Is it kinetic in nature or static in nature?

3) Remember that the only horizontal force acting on the upper mass is the frictional force regardless of nature.

For the bottom mass:

$$F-f=m_1a_1$$

For the top mass, $f=m_2a_2$ and $\mu_?m_2g=m_2a_2$.

Then:

$$F-\mu_?m_2g=m_1a_1$$
$$F-m_2a_2=m_1a_1$$